# $\alpha$ is an irrational number. Is $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\{ n\alpha\}$ always positive?

Tags: analysis, irrational-numbers, limsup-and-liminf

We know that $$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ n\{ n\alpha\}=L\left(\alpha\right)$$ exists and $L\left(\alpha\right)\geq 0$.
Then, is the limit always greater than  $0,\ \forall\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$?
$\{n\alpha\}$ is the fractional part of $n\alpha$, i.e. $n\alpha-\left[n\alpha\right]$.
I know that there are infinitely many rational numbers $\frac{p}{q}$ satisfies $\left|\alpha-\frac{p}{q}\right|<\frac{1}{q^2}$, but if $\frac{1}{q^2}$ is modified as $\frac{C}{q^k}$($C$ is a given constant), does there still exist infinitely many such rational numbers?
Moreover, what about the special cases $\alpha=\sqrt{2}$ or $\alpha=2^\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: What is "the fractional part of $\alpha$"?

Comment: It seems to me that the $\liminf$ could be zero.  I believe that a number with long stretches of zeros in the decimal expansion should get the job done (e.g. something like [Liouville's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number)).

Comment: @XanderHenderson You are right, for Lioucille's number it is easy to construct some $k_n$ such that $10^{k_n} \{ 10^{k_n} \alpha \} \to 0$.

Comment: It is easy to argue that any number with the property that there are infinitely many $(p,q)$ with $$\left| \alpha \frac{p}{q} \right| < \frac{1}{q^{2+\epsilon}}$$ leads to a limit of 0. In particular, any Liouville number satisfies this property, and there are infinitely many of them.

Comment: @N.S. Ah yes, I almost forgot it… Then what about a special case $\alpha=\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: For quadratic irrationalities, the $\lim\inf$ is strictly positive.